# Issue facing in rtabmap_ros during localization at night time

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am working on one project for which I am using rtabmap_ros package for localization, but I am facing one issue in it.
As we knew rtabmap_ros package uses the following image data

```
                  <remap from="rgb/image" to="/camera/qhd/image_color"/>
          <remap from="depth/image" to="/camera/qhd/image_depth_rect"/>
          <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/qhd/camera_info"/>
```

for mapping and localization. During day time the pkg localizes the mobile robot perfectly without any issue But at evening time, as we make light's on, it doesn't gets localize at some position. Please can any one suggest me Why it's not getting localize and what must be issue in. Or do we have to remap this image topic to other images type. Also Is there any parameter to solve this issue in rtabmap_ros pkg?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252145/issue-facing-in-rtabmap_ros-during-localization-at-night-time/) by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Illumination/lighting change is challenging for image-based localization. The visual features can be very different between night and day. If you have a LiDAR, rtabmap could still localize when visual localization is not working for a short time. Another solution could be to map another time at night time, so you can localize either in the "night" map or the "day" map. If some places have similar lighting between day and night and rtabmap is able to visually find a loop closure, rtabmap would be able to merge the maps together (so no need to switch manually between day and night maps).

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atul Divekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27747/atul-divekar/) on 2017-02-01**:
Sorry for the late reply. And your suggestion work for me. Thanks for reply.